# event form.shown works but form.load doesn't

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Basic 2010, and i'm coding in c for a program i'm constructing, my issue is is that i have a Media.SoundPlayer set up and I want it to activate when a form loads so my code looks like this (edit: this code doesn't work the sound doesn't play on load in debug and i get no errors)

```
Private Sub BGMusic(ByVal x As Integer)
        Dim msp As New Media.SoundPlayer
        Dim Music As String = Install + "\Music\innmusic.wav"
        msp.SoundLocation = Music
        If x = 1 Then
            msp.Play()
        Else
            msp.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub Innmenu_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            BGMusic(1)
    End Sub
```

also i'd like to note that Install + "\Music\innmusic.wav" is a valid path because I can set up a button to run BGMusic(1) and that also plays the music. For my purposes, form.shown will work but i'd like to know what is wrong for my future programs so that I can use form.load

Comment: `+` is not the string concatenation operator in VB.  `&` is.

Comment: @Dan-o + and & in VB.net works both fine for string concatenation.

Comment: i'll try debugging a shot, and the same code works on different form pages, but on certain ones it doesn't seem to execute

Comment: Note: You should only use `+` for string concat if you have Option Strict On.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that your `Install` variable which you did not show where you declare it, is either empty or not initialized properly. I'll give you an illustration below:

```
Public Class Innmenu

Dim Install As String = ""

Private Sub Innmenu_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BGMusic(1) ' It will not play because Install is still empty
End Sub

Private Sub BGMusic(ByVal x As Integer)
    Dim msp As New Media.SoundPlayer
    Dim Music As String = Install + "\Music\innmusic.wav"
    msp.SoundLocation = Music
    If x = 1 Then
        msp.Play()
    Else
        msp.Stop()
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Install = "C:\" 'Let us assume that your folder Music and file innmusic.wav is in C:
BGMusic(1) ' Music will now play because Install has now the right value assigned

End Sub
```

Try to do `Try Catch` by the way for your `BGMusic` Method like:

```
Private Sub BGMusic(ByVal x As Integer)
    Dim msp As New Media.SoundPlayer
    Dim Music As String = Install + "\Music\innmusic.wav"
    msp.SoundLocation = Music

    Try
       If x = 1 Then
        msp.Play()
       Else
        msp.Stop()
       End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub
```

In order that you will have feedback on your error if there is any.

Comment: I know the install variable isn't empty because like i said in my question a button does activate BGMusic(1) but i feel like i'm missing some launch order because on some of my forms this code works and on others it doesn't and i copied and pasted the code

Comment: Are you sure that your Install variable has the right value on it? Have you tried debugging/tracing it? By the way did you use threading on this one? Because if it is there is a chance that it is change somewhere.